# Tailwind CSS, positioning one image over another

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to position an image over image. Basically I want the image to fit correctly at the chest area position on the hoodie, but it's not coming out properly. How do I do it in a clean way that is responsive as well?

My code:

```
<div className="basis-1/2">
  <div className="max-w-lg container mx-auto">
    <img className="w-full" src={`${router.basePath}/assets/images/Hoodie black label.jpg`} alt="Empty Hoodie"/>
    <div className="place-items-center">
      <img className="w-1/6 absolute top-1/3 right 1/4 place-items-center h-40 w-40" src={urlvalue} alt="Picked NFT to Print"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So this is a steal NFT graphic and print it on a shirt script?  As far as assistance, have you considered including Bootstrap as well? Might be easier to use if you are having container positioning issues.

Comment: not steal , much more to it, let me check bootstrap as well, any links to what to look for?

Comment: "Borrow" a graphic someone else made, and profit off it. that sound better ? XD

Comment: But here is something else I spotted just now, your SRC has a space in the name:
router.basePath}/assets/images/Hoodie black  label.jpg

Can you rename the file to be black_label .. with an _ in it and change the src to use the _

Comment: Bootstrap can be found here --
https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: haha still no, having a licensing of owner involved in it :)

Comment: Ohh okay well then that changes everything, quite the opposite of what I said .. Godspeed.

Comment: haha , yeah, idea is to solve that problem and give an authentic, verified tag kinda thing

Comment: Oh okay that makes some sense there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overlay an image over another like this,

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

    <div class="relative mix-blend-lighten">
      <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61ktWbf0z4L._UX679_.jpg" alt="BannerImage" class="absolute h-[] w-full object-cover object-right " />
      <img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back04.jpg" alt="BannerImage" class="absolute h-[20vh] w-[30vh] object-cover object-right mx-44 mt-44 sm:mx-72 sm:mt-72" />
    </div>
```

But since both the image had `absolute` position, then you have to add different margins for the upper image for each screen breakpoints, so that it lies always on chest area of hoodie image.

Comment: hey thanks man, this worked well, but now its not responsive

Comment: That's what I mentioned,now you have to take care of every screen breakpoint

Comment: Yes, done , i was able to do that :) thanks man.. any idea on how i can blur only the image borders ?

Comment: Kindly raise another question for this?